# Is M a finite set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If:

i) $f$, $g$, $h$ are functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ (domain of the functions is $\mathbb{R}$ and the range is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$),

ii) $A = \{x ∈ \mathbb{R}; f(x)≠g(x)\}$ is a finite set, $B = \{x ∈ \mathbb{R}; g(x)≠h(x)\}$ is a finite set,

Is $M = \{x ∈ \mathbb{R}; f(x)≠h(x)\}$ also a finite set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Show that $M\subseteq A\cup B$.

Comment: If x∈M, then there exist a, b, c ∈ R such that a≠b, f(x)=a, g(x)=c, h(x)=b. If c=a, then c≠b and h(x)≠g(x) which means x∈B and therefore x∈A∪B. If c=b, then c≠a and f(x)≠g(x) which means x∈A and therefore x∈A∪B. If c≠a and c≠b then f(x)≠g(x) and h(x)≠g(x) which means x∈(A∩B) and therfore x∈A∪B.

Comment: @Olexandr You don't need the last sentence, but otherwise good job! Personally, I would be more comfortable showing that the complement of $A\cup B$ is contained in the complement of $M$, but it makes little difference in the end.